# How can I make caves with Unity's terrain creator?

Tags: c#, 3d, unity, terrain

With Unity's terrain creator, I can't simply make a "hole" on the mesh.

I don't know how I would make cave-like structures other than using "rock" meshes for the roof (wich will indeed look weird) or using portals (wich I always have problems with -- the teleportation isn't thruly smooth and there's always a small "jump". You know, not like a fluid thing.

How can I make caves in terrain with Unity?

Comment: Why not use one mesh matrix for the floor and one for the ceiling?

Comment: Maybe it's just that I'm that slow, but I really don't imagine what you're trying to point right there.

Comment: I was wrong. The most recommended way is using Blender.

Comment: Unity terrain is heightmap based, which fundamentally cannot support overhangs (such as caves and arches). This isn't really possible without making the roof from some other mesh. Unity Terrain was never "intended" to make caves and such. In fact, like all heightmap systems, it doesn't even do cliffs very well.

Comment: Okay, there's no "intended" way then.

But how I should do it? Portal tricks wich don't look very good? Teleportation? A bunch of modeling work I suck at?

==
And yes I really need to make caves.

Comment: You could try implementing voxel-based terrain with marching cubes (its own can of worms, especially in Unity). But there is no silver bullet. Pick a method and give it a shot. If it doesn't work, try another method.

Comment: I never used it, but Robert Yang once posted a possible solution for this on [his blog](http://www.blog.radiator.debacle.us/2012/08/how-to-dig-holes-in-unity3d-terrains.html). Maybe that works?

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Unity **2019.3**, you can properly cut holes in terrain surface (see https://blogs.unity3d.com/2019/08/27/unity-2019-3-beta-is-now-available/#attachment_82836)
However, this **won't** create the cave mesh for you.

If you are looking for a terrain hole system that creates meshes automatically you may want to use a plugin like this one: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/terrain/digger-terrain-caves-overhangs-135178

Answer (score 2):

You can't make a cave in Unity's terrain system natively because it uses a 2d heightmap, where each point can only have one height.

This allows for some major optimizations (and a radically different approach) compared to a system that allows for 3D height definition.

But there is an easy work around that AAA games have used (including certain CryENGINE games). Simply make a hole in the terrain and place a mesh representing the cave.

There are different approaches to making holes in a terrain like Unity's. I like the approach taken [here](http://www.blog.radiator.debacle.us/2012/08/how-to-dig-holes-in-unity3d-terrains.html) for being robust and easy to modify.

Comment: There's also a plug-in on the asset store you can use https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/8277